# Javascript promise, nested functions

Tags: javascript, promise

my question is that im running node.js, and i have 2 functions that needs to be run in a specific order, however they are not returning a promise at this this. So i wonder how would i rewrite this to make sure that the main function would return a promise, and if i have nested functions, do i just run the 2nd function from the 1st functions resolve?

Here is the code:

```
handleMd5Convert = (file) => {
  fs.readFile(file, (err, buf) => {
    fs.rename(file, directoryPath + md5(buf) + '.mp3', (err) => {
      if (err) console.log('ERROR: ' + err);
    })
  })
})
```

HandleMd5Convert should be able to to .`then()`

/Alex

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to wrap the whole thing in a `new Promise()` and use `resolve()` & `reject()` to handle success and errors:

```
handleMd5Convert = (file) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(file, (err, buf) => {
      if (err) return reject(err)
      fs.rename(file, directoryPath + md5(buf) + '.mp3', (err) => {
        if (err) return reject(err);
        resolve()
      })
    })
  })
}

handleMd5Convert('test.txt')
.then(() => console.log("done"))
.catch(err => console.log("error:", err))
```

Comment: The resolve() here, it shouldnt have anything inside of it? or just emtpy () is fine? if i were to console log this now, it would return undefined, but maybe it shouldnt return anything

Comment: @AlexanderMunckAfRosenschöld it's not required, but if you have a value you want to retrieve in the `then()` you can resolve that value. You would: `resolve(someValue)` then after the promise resolves you could get it in `then(someValue => {/* use some value */})`. It doesn't seem like you have anything to resolve in this case though, but maybe something like the final file name would make sense.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help!

Comment: @AlexanderMunckAfRosenschöld You should mark the answer as "accepted", if it worked for you. Do this by clicking the tick mark below vote buttons of this answer.

Comment: Why did you write `return reject(err)` instead of `reject(err)`? (inside the callback for `fs.readFile` function)

Comment: @Arjun `reject()` by itself doesn't exit the function. I didn't want the rest of the function to execute to a used return.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a promise using `new Promise`  like this:

```
var myPromise = function(resolve) {
    someAsyncMethod(param1, callback(x){
        resolve (x);
    });
}
```

This way `myPromise` is able to `.then()`. the promise will be completed only after you call `resolve()`

```
myPromise.then(function(result){
    // Your code here...
});
```