# Added return promise but then doesn't execute

Tags: javascript

According to this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52174259/2690257
if I wish to convert a method into a promise function I insert `return New Promise in the code.`

I currently have this method.

```
function takeWebshot(fLine, sLine, pID, prodPlate) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      webshot('citylocsblog.com/preview/productpreview/testy.html?prod=' + prodPlate, '../screenshot/' + pID +'.png', options, function(err) {
        if(err) { return reject(err); } resolve()
      });
    })
```

Here in the above I had done so.
The method webshot is a module I'm using in npm that uses phantom js to take a screen shot.  After it's execution it will return an error which is why at the end I put the function resolve or reject to fulfill the promise.

I call the method takeWebshot like so and then I execute a then:

```
takeWebshot(firstLine, secondLine, previewID, productPlate)
.then(() => console.log("promise works!"))
```

Console.log on then does not do anything.  I get no errors just doesn't fire.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think you want `if(err) { return reject(err); } resolve()`, resolve() never executes in the code you provided

Comment: Updated code still doesn't work. @ChrisLi

Comment: What does it suppose to do after promise resolves

Comment: .then() can handle an onresolve and onrejected functions. Have you tried seeing if either of them are called? If you look at this link you can see that your code and my code are similar in shape (and mine works). Your looks like it should so add the onrejected to your then() and let us know if it gets hit. https://jsbin.com/xaxirifoyi/edit?js,console

Answer (score -1):

You only are resolving the promise if the `webshot` callback has an error, try resolving if there is no `err`:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      webshot('...' + prodPlate, '../screenshot/' + pID +'.png', options, function(err) {
        //error
        if(err) {
          reject(err);
        }

        //no error
        resolve();
      });
    })
```

Comment: Are you sure you are reaching the callback to webshot, does it even get called?

Comment: According to the documentation it’s supposed to.  I know I’m getting the web shot to fire cause it saves the image I want.

Comment: I believe the error is that webshot is not calling that callback.  After digging into it extensively I think this is the error.  @Victor Babel